# Can someone check my Dart code and tell me where I'm making mistake in returning data from my screen as a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am stuck here for the past 20 days in returning data in my app from the other screen. I'm new to programming and need help. I've been searching through all the internet to find an answer related to my query but nothing is helping though. I ask my fellow SO guys to please help.
You can look at the entire code which I've made open [here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp).
My code:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
    children: <Widget>[
      FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          final newList = await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
            ),
          );
          setState(() {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: newList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Container(
                  child: Text('item: $newList'),
                );
              },
            );
          });
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

The screen where Navigator.pop() is used:

```
final Set saved = Set();
class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
 }

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Add to Favorites!'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 53,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          checkColor: Colors.white,
          value: saved.contains(index),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              // isChecked = val;           // changed
              // if(val == true){           // changed
              //   __saved.add(context);     // changed
              // } else{                    // changed
              //   __saved.remove(context);  // changed
              // }                          // changed
              if (val == true) {
                saved.add(index);
              } else {
                saved.remove(index);
              }
            });
          },
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Text(nameOfSite[index]),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    foregroundColor: Colors.red,
    child: Icon(Icons.check),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop<Set>(context, saved);
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: as I already told you to need to read the docs, how to pass data from one class to another and how to store data permanently for your app.

The type of code you have given here, purely looks you haven't gone through the Flutter docs.

Comment: @OMiShah yes I read the docs thoroughly but still I'm not able to correct myself. Thats why I'm asking the question Sir. Thank you.

Comment: @OMiShah and I definitely know what `Navigator.push()` does.

Comment: I am so sorry :(

Comment: you can tag me in future, I will help you surely. Sorry for being rude :(

Comment: @OMiShah then help me right now if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You have to move out return `ListView` to the same layer with `FloatingActionButton`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SecondPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  Set newList = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: newList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                child: Text('item: ${newList.elementAt(index)}'),
              );
            },
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              newList = await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
                ),
              );
              setState(() {});
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

final Set saved = Set();

class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add to Favorites!'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 53,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CheckboxListTile(
              activeColor: Colors.red,
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              value: saved.contains(index),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  // isChecked = val;           // changed
                  // if(val == true){           // changed
                  //   __saved.add(context);     // changed
                  // } else{                    // changed
                  //   __saved.remove(context);  // changed
                  // }                          // changed
                  if (val == true) {
                    saved.add(index);
                  } else {
                    saved.remove(index);
                  }
                });
              },
              title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text('nameOfSite[index]'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        foregroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.check),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop<Set>(context, saved);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yo...finally its working!! Thank you so much. Ok one more thing. What if I have a list of names that I want to display ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']. After trying your code, this is where I'm stuck now! Any idea? I just want to display the name of the item that has been clicked!

Comment: instead of save index do you mean saved.add( yourName[index] );

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps, thanks.

Comment: its saying `type 'int' is not a subtype of 'String'` so its not working. I had actually tried this before commenting my query! So any other idea?

Comment: could you post full code to another question? need to reproduce your problem before bug, thanks.

Comment: I have provided the full code in the question above, you can take a look! And there is a `nameOfSite` list in the `lists.dart` file. you can check that!

Comment: could you try this   final Set<String> saved = Set(); I am upgrading my android and flutter will need some time.

Comment: i've succesfully iterated the items, the names and the images! it was like this: `Text(nameOfSite[newList.elementAt(index)])` and for images - `Image.asset('lib/images/${images[newList.elementAt(index)]}')`. it would have never been possible without your help. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `SecondPage` and `FavoriteList` that I made

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aioapp2/lists.dart';

Set<int> favorites = {};

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        _getFavoriteList(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.edit,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => EditFavorites(),
                  ),
                ).then((updatedFavorites) {
                  if (updatedFavorites != null)
                    setState(() {
                      favorites = updatedFavorites;
                    });
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _getFavoriteList() {
    if (favorites?.isNotEmpty == true)
        return _FavoriteList();
    else
      return _EmptyFavoriteList();

  }
}

class _EmptyFavoriteList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Add Your Favorite Sites Here!❤',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    size: 150,
                    color: Colors.blue[100],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _FavoriteList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: favorites.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
          ),
          title: Text(nameOfSite[favorites.elementAt(index)]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


//Its FavoriteList Page. I changed the name
class EditFavorites extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditFavoritesState createState() => _EditFavoritesState();
}

class _EditFavoritesState extends State<EditFavorites> {
  final _editableFavorites = <int>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    _editableFavorites.addAll(favorites);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add to Favorites!'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.done),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop<Set>(context, _editableFavorites);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      //backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: nameOfSite.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
              ),
              title: Text(nameOfSite[index]),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: _editableFavorites.contains(index)
                    ? Icon(
                  Icons.favorite,
                  color: Colors.red,
                )
                    : Icon(
                  Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_editableFavorites.contains(index))
                      _editableFavorites.remove(index);
                    else
                      _editableFavorites.add(index);
                  });
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Just replace `secondtab.dart` with this code.

Comment: dude. this is exactly the way i want it to be. this was really helpful. i've used this code to make my app and its working perfectly! thank you so much. i'll study this code thoroughly and i'll make sure to not make any mistakes in future thank you again.